# MySQL Subquery, Join and Rank Query - Why very slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, inner-join

My query takes forever to load with only 800+ rows in `members` and 5,100+ rows in `members_points`.

Is there a more efficient approach to this that I'm overlooking, or another way to write this query using MySQL 5.5.33?

*UPDATE: 5.5 is my localhost and 5.7 is live server. not seeing any noticeable difference.

Here is what i have so far - Thank you for your feedback

```
  $result = $conn->query("
  SELECT subquery.*, 
         @rank := @rank + 1 `rank`
  FROM (SELECT m.id, 
               m.Name,
               m.Column_1,
               m.Column_2,
               m.Column_3,
               SUM(m.id = mp.id_from) total_sent,
               SUM(m.id = mp.id_to) total_received,
               SUM(m.id = mp.id_from) - SUM(m.id = mp.id_to) `points`
        FROM members m
        INNER JOIN members_points mp
        WHERE Account_Active LIKE 'TRUE'
        GROUP BY m.id, 
                 m.Name) subquery, (SELECT @rank := 0) variable
  ORDER BY `points` DESC;
  ");
```

Comment: you do know that mysql 5.5 is very old and deprecated?

Comment: are you suggesting that the issue isn't the code, but the server setup?

Comment: as always optimize querys need an EXPLAIN and Table definitions, but mysql 5.5 is too old, so try to use 5.7  and see if there is a quicker. that is a smal database, so migration should run quickly as should you query with indexes

Comment: What table is `Account_Active` in?  It makes a _big_ difference in optimizing, and I can't tell from what you have provided.  And is it a `VARCHAR`?  The test does not check for true/false.  Please qualify the column _and_ provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Account active is in the members table. It is TINYTEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT subquery.*, 
         @rank := @rank + 1 `rank`
  FROM (SELECT m.id, 
               m.Name,
               m.Column_1,
               m.Column_2,
               m.Column_3,
               SUM(m.id = mp.id_from) total_sent,
               SUM(m.id = mp.id_to) total_received,
               SUM(m.id = mp.id_from) - SUM(m.id = mp.id_to) `points`
        FROM members m
        INNER JOIN members_points mp
        WHERE Account_Active LIKE 'TRUE'
        GROUP BY m.id, 
                 m.Name) subquery, (SELECT @rank := 0) variable
  ORDER BY `points` DESC;
  ");
```

Start with the counts before doing any `JOINs`.

```
SELECT id_from, COUNT(*) AS from_ct FROM members_points GROUP BY 1
SELECT id_to,   COUNT(*) AS   to_ct FROM members_points GROUP BY 1
```

Then use those as subqueries and work outward.

There could be a problem if you do or don't want to include an *active* member chatting with an *inactive* member.  How many rows in the tables?

Now see if this looks right for `subquery`:

```
SELECT m.id, 
           m.Name,
           m.Column_1,
           m.Column_2,
           m.Column_3,
           froms.from_ct total_sent,
           tos.to_ct     total_received,
           froms.from_ct - tos.to_ct `points`
    FROM members m
    JOIN ( SELECT id_from, COUNT(*) AS from_ct FROM members_points GROUP BY 1
         ) AS froms  ON froms.id_from = m.id
    JOIN ( SELECT id_to,   COUNT(*) AS   to_ct FROM members_points GROUP BY 1
         ) AS tos    ON tos.id_to = m.id
    JOIN members_points mp
    WHERE m.Account_Active = 'TRUE'
    GROUP BY m.id, 
             m.Name
```

Comment: Hi Rick. MySQL syntax is def. not my strength, although I understand the concept, I'm afraid I don't understand it that well to implement what you are speaking of. Only active members can exchange points, inactive members are hidden. There's only 800+ in members table and 5100+ in member_points... Thinking if the better route is to add more 3 more columns in the members table to sum up the transactions (from | to | from-to) and every transaction writes to the members_points, then updates the members totals? ... I just feel that isn't the most efficient route?

Comment: @Andrew - The inefficiency is (I think) primarily due to needing to filter on 'active' before calculating the `SUMs`.  Will you get the same answer if `WHERE` clause is removed?

Comment: Other than including the inactive members into the query, it doesn't make a noticeable difference, query still takes over a minute and a half to run...also tried limiting the results to 10, but also makes no difference as the calculation needs to run first to find out which 10 are the highest ranked

Comment: @Andrew - I took it a step further.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for. Shaved nearly a 1 - 1 1/2 min off of the load time.... Thank you Rick for sharing your knowledge and helping me understand a little bit better.